# FLASK app: Sending data from a Form through another script while one "input" is a dynamic paragraph

Tags: python, flask

I have a from with three possible inputs to submit and send through a seperate script that then generates JSON data.

The problem is however while two inputs are actual inputs = one email and one being a nummer. The third one is not a really traditional input.

```
<form  action="{ url_for('handle_data') }}" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Speryear">SPER jaar</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" value="2" name="Speryear" min=0 max=10 />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail">Verzendings mail</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="email" name="inputEmail" required />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="url-panel">
            <p> <b>Url:</b></p>
            <p id="api-url" name="api-url"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="search" type="submit" class="btn-primary">
    Aanvraag indienen</button>
</form>


@app.route('/handle_data', methods=['POST'])
def handle_data():
    sper_year = request.form["Speryear"]
    email = request.form["inputEmail"]
    url = request.form["api-url"]
    Requested_data = GIPOD_converter.main(url, sper_year, email)
return Requested_data
```

The third input is actually a paragraph which is dynamically based on the values of a second form (the primary from) for the data requests. According to this post here:
[Sending data from a html non-input to Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47859999/sending-data-from-a-html-non-input-to-flask)

*HTML forms only send along  tagged values to the remote endpoint when a "submit" input is pressed.*

I have tried to make this paragraph a data input but the thing is this will break the javascript I have for that specific id. Aka a the URL part that I want cannot be generated in the input field. So can my code get the paragraph from this?

Edits done as per answer.

Comment: have you thought of encoding it to Base64(in JS) and then decoding it in flask?

Comment: Uh sorry kind of an amateur of this. I am now trying to solve this in Javascript. By getting the value of the paragraph and putting that into a input box.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should end the app route with:

```
return Requested_data
```

Also, you do not define correctly to the url form, i.e.:

```
url = request.form["api-url"]
```

Comment: Yeah I know this is still being under construction but I will ad the suggestion in as, my main question still remains though can I still get the data aka the url variable from this paragraph?

Comment: Also added in a edit thank you but I was still writing it. Again the question remains? Wil it take the paragraph is an input for the variable.

Comment: No it wont. I think you should take care of that part with javascript. :)

Comment: Oh man. And my current Javascript will not work on setting that input, it will only work on paragraph with id = #api-url...oh wait facepalm. document.getElementById("api-url").value = url.